# Non-glass heating element for an etching tank

Tags: pcb-fabrication

I have been using below glass heating element (the part name is [ET20](http://www.velleman.eu/products/view/?id=369502)) on my etching tank.

[image]

The problem is that the glass is too gentle that breaks very easy for many reasons, I already needed to replace a few of them.

I wonder if you could suggest me any non-glass heating element for an etching tank that is not fragile and durable to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Titanium is used commercially. Since they're sold for aquariums they might be economical enough and work for you (if the other materials and the Ti are compatible with your etchant).

Answer (score 2):

There are also heating mats.  These are rubber and many are suitable for being submerged. The Redi-Heat Heavy-Duty Propagation Heat Mats have many temps and sizes (The ones I own have 120F max. temp.)  They are also waterproof.  You can put your tank onto the mat, or attach the mat to the outside, or leave the mat on the inside (After checking for etchant resistance).

In my days of dark-room film developing, this is what we used to keep our chemistry at the proper temperature levels.